# Attempt to assign property "free_left" on null

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

```
  $position = getPositionLocation($id);            
$extra = UserExtra::where('user_id', $posid)->first();            
if ($position = 1) {                
$extra->free_left += 1;            
} else {                
$extra->free_right += 2;            
}           
 $extra->save();
```

This is were my error is
$extra->free_left += 1;

```
            $extra->free_left +== 1;
```

Comment: According to that error message, `$extra` is NULL.  So this call is not returning any object: `UserExtra::where('user_id', $posid)->first();`.  I suggest doing a `var_dump($posid)` to check what is in this variable, and if it is what you are expecting.

Comment: `->first()` can return `null`, and `null->free_left += 1` is not valid PHP code. You need to check first, i.e. `if ($extra) { ... }`. Or, use `->firstOrFail()` to trigger an automatic error/redirect if a `UserExtra` Model instance is not found. Never **assume** a variable is set when pulling data from your database; check that it is first. Also, `if ($position = 1) {` is a common beginner mistake. You're using `=`, which is assignment, and when assigning `1` to a variable `$position`, will always return `true`. Simple code would be `$extra->free_left += ($position == 1 ? 1 : 2);`

Comment: I did code fails even with '== 1'

Comment: ->firstOrFail() Gives Registration page 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 - You can use [is_null](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) and the `!`, just to prevent that `NULL` error from `$extra`.

```
$position = getPositionLocation($id);
$extra = UserExtra::where('user_id', $id)->first();

if(!is_null($extra)) {
    if ($position == 1) { //! don't do just one equal (=), it will change variable.
        $extra->free_left += 1;
    } else {
        $extra->free_right = 2;
    }
    $extra->save();
}
```

#2 - In laravel you can use the [->firstOrFail()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-first-or-fail) to prevent this error without more condition on your code.

```
$extra = UserExtra::where('user_id', $id)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: This is incorrect, sorry. `$extra` is `null`, as `->first()` can return `null` **OR** a `UserExtra` instance. Your code would still fail on `$extra->free_left = ...`, as `null->free_left` is not valid PHP. You're correct on the `==` vs `=` part, but testing it, [your code still fails](https://3v4l.org/QH0E1).

Comment: @TimLewis yeah you are right. added a second way and changed my base code.

Comment: That's much better. Sidenote, you generally don't need `is_null($model)` if `$model` is from `->first()`; instances are "truthy", and `null` is "falsey", so `if($model)` is sufficient  (but either works, just a preference thing)

Answer (score -1):

Check if property **free_left** exists on the $extra object.

Comment: `$extra` is not an Object, it is `null`, and you can't check if a property exists on `null`, it simply doesn't... `null->property` is not valid PHP.